# Posso rodar um programa de Python automaticamente fora do meu computador?

Tags: python

Bom dia pessoal, eu fiz um script de Python que procura em vários sites as ocorrencias de algumas palavras e armazena em banco de dados SQL. Eu gostaria de acompanhar a ocorrência dessas palavras ao longo do tempo, mas não quero ficar clicando para executa-lo ou deixar o computador ligado para ficar executando essa rotina. 
  Gostaria por exemplo que a cada 6 horas ele fizesse essa pesquisa e salvasse os resultados. Eu consigo fazer ele ficar rodando em algum servidor? O que eu precisaria aprender para que isso funcione?
Obrigado!

Comment: Procure por crontab ou cronjob. Alguns servidores disponibilizam acesso a essa ferramenta de agendamento de tarefas pelo CPanel. É possível fazer via linha de comando também caso possua acesso via SSH.

Comment: Você prefere que o script fique rodando o tempo inteiro, e a cada 6h ele execute o procedimento? ou você prefere que o mesmo seja requisitado por um agente externo?

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann a idéia é rodar sozinho mesmo. Tipo de 12 em 12 horas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um serviço de hospedagem como o [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) para executar o seu script. 
Neste serviço você pode criar uma conta gratuita e criar ou fazer o upload do seu script. É possível executar o seu script utilizando uma console no browser ou então realizar o agendamento para execução periódica. Também é possível utilizar um banco de dados mysql disponibilizado pelo host. Na conta gratuita há alguns limites de armazenamento, acesso à internet e CPU que sua aplicação pode utilizar, mas é possível que no seu caso não deva exceder nenhum deles.

[image: Dashboard de acesso do pythonanywhere]

Comment: Esse site é maravilhoso ele funciona como se fosse uma VPS, com 5 dolares você ja consegue ter uma conta razoavel que dá para fazer bastante coisa.